# Different post title, keywords and description

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts

Can I add for example a post called "Hello world", but to customly select the title, description and keywords for the page that will appear for the search engines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any SEO plugin. For example, `Yoast SEO` or `All in One SEO`, which can be found in WordPress repository.